# connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while trying to get scala app

Tags: linux, nginx

I'm tryign to get running an scala app which is listening in port 9000, I have setup nginx to listen such port but it seems like something is not correct,

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9000: Connection refused
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ curl localhost
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.14.1</center>
</body>
</html>

2021/02/27 03:08:52 [error] 3289#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://0.0.0.0:9000/", host: "localhost"
    2021/02/27 03:08:55 [error] 3289#0: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://0.0.0.0:9000/", host: "localhost"
    2021/02/27 03:08:56 [error] 3289#0: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://0.0.0.0:9000/", host: "localhost"
    2021/02/27 03:08:57 [error] 3289#0: *7 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://0.0.0.0:9000/", host: "localhost"
    2021/02/27 03:15:53 [error] 3289#0: *9 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://0.0.0.0:9000/", host: "localhost"
    2021/02/27 03:16:02 [error] 3289#0: *11 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://0.0.0.0:9000/", host: "localhost"
```

my `nginx.config` file looks like this

```
    worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;

  proxy_buffering    off;
  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;

  upstream my-backend {
     server 0.0.0.0:9000;
  }

  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  0.0.0.0;
    location / {
       proxy_pass http://my-backend;
    }
  }

}
```

app log and port listening

```
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:111)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:78)
        at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:200)
        at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:155)
        at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
        at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:54)
        at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:30)
        at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:270)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:67)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:212)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:407)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:275)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$100(HikariPool.java:71)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:706)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:692)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:64)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:150)
        ... 15 more
[vagrant@localhost cookbooks]$ ss -lntp | grep 9000
[vagrant@localhost cookbooks]$ ss -lntp | grep 80
LISTEN    0         128                0.0.0.0:80               0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN    0         128                   [::]:80                  [::]:*
[vagrant@localhost cookbooks]$ ss -lntp | grep 9000
[vagrant@localhost cookbooks]$
```

Comment: I have restarted nginx and target gcs-app and retried, and issue persist

Comment: Why do you think your scala app is listening on port 9000?

Comment: this is the target app https://github.com/mundacho/proyecto-gcs/blob/master/gcs-app/conf/application.conf#L6

Comment: That doesn't say anything about why you think it is running or listening on any particular port.

Comment: To confirm that something is listening on TCP port 9000, use `ss -lntp | grep 9000`, preferably as root. The error "connection refused" is a strong indication that nothing listens at this port at this time.

Comment: @berndbausch I attached the command execution and log, it seems like there is an exception while trying  to connect to DB hence service is stoped, I'll solve the connection issue and then see if the issue persist

thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `0.0.0.0` in the `server` line of your `nginx.config` with the IP address or hostname on which the scala app is listening.
Even if it is listening on the `any` interface (`0.0.0.0`), you cannot use 0.0.0.0 on the `server` line.
You can use the loopback interface (`localhost` or `127.0.0.1`) in this case.

Your scala app might in fact be listening on port 9000, but it might be bound to the external network interface (`eth0`, `wlan0`, `p2p1` or something else, depending on hardware and Linux distribution) instead of the `any` interface (`0.0.0.0`).
In that case you have to use the address it is listening on instead of the loopback address 127.0.0.1.

You can find out the listining address of the scala app using `fuser 9000/tcp` or some equivalent `lsof` or `ss` command as pointed out by @berndbausch.